# Laravel. Как выбрать записи за последний день

Tags: laravel, laravel5

У меня есть таблица message с полями id, message и added_on(TIMESTAMP).
В ней есть записи за разные дни.
Как выбрать все записи только за последний день?

Comment: elequent используете?

Comment: да, использую eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте такое условие для выборки

```
->whereRaw('date(added_on) = (select date(max(added_on)) from message)')
```

Comment: это не подойдет. Нужны все сообщения за последний день, который есть в базе данных. Например, в базе есть сообщения за 2019-02-03 и 2019-02-06. Нужно выбрать все сообщения за 2019-02-06. Сегодня 2019-02-09

Comment: исправил ответ с учетом вашего уточнения

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выбираю ваш ответ лучшим

Answer (score 2):

Правильный путь:

```
$posts = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю